# No error code during Deploy using Web Deploy 3.5

Tags: iis, webdeploy

[image: screeshot of the error in visual]

I'm totally new to web deployement. I did set up a deploy on one of my project, I did the same thing on another one. But when I try to publish my website, I have this error with no code.

I don't even know where to search for the log file on the IIS server. Can you tell me, Everything is running with default configuration. I just need to know where to find the information so I can publish my website.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found this blog where the solution is explained : http://bartwullems.blogspot.fr/2013/01/webdeploy-error-systemunauthorizedacces.html

I didn't know where to look for the logs but once I found the right log, the error is : System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation. at System.Security.AccessControl.Win32.SetSecurityInfo